# Perl Socket accept failing in thread on Windows

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets

We've got a Perl system which opens listener sockets, and then spawns threads to actually accept and act on connections. We're running on Windows Server 2008, and running Perl 5.8.8 (it's quite an old system).

(As an aside, this works fine on Linux, where we're using forking - but the implementation of *fork* on Windows is less than optimal).

We're creating the socket using this code:

```
use Socket;

...;

unless (
    ($rSock) = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        LocalPort => $aChannelConfig{$sChannel}->{nPort},
        Proto     => 'tcp',
        Type      => SOCK_STREAM,
        Reuse     => 1,
        Listen    => $aChannelConfig{$sChannel}->{nListen},
    )
    and $rSock
    )
{
    $sErrNote = "Cannot create tcp listener socket: sChannel=$sChannel sService=>$aChannelConfig{$sChannel}->{nPort} Err=$!";
}
```

When the spawned processes come to accept the socket, only the *first one* works properly.

**The problem is** that subsequent processes just get undef from IO::Socket::accept - in the core IO::Socket::accept code below, the call to ***_accept_*** returns undef (we're not using timeouts).

```
sub accept {
    @_ == 1 || @_ == 2 or croak 'usage $sock->accept([PKG])';
    my $sock    = shift;
    my $pkg     = shift || $sock;
    my $timeout = ${*$sock}{'io_socket_timeout'};
    my $new     = $pkg->new( Timeout => $timeout );
    my $peer    = undef;

    print("!!! in IO::Socket::accept sock=$socket pkg=$pkg timeout=$timeout new=$new\n");
    if ( defined $timeout ) {
        require IO::Select;

        my $sel = new IO::Select $sock;

        unless ( $sel->can_read($timeout) ) {
            $@ = 'accept: timeout';
            $! = ( exists &Errno::ETIMEDOUT ? &Errno::ETIMEDOUT : 1 );
            return;
        }
    }

    $peer = accept( $new, $sock )
        or return;

    return wantarray
        ? ( $new, $peer )
        : $new;
}
```

Presumably we need to do something with the socket options to allow different threads to *accept* on it.

Can someone give me some pointers please?

**Edit**
Our call to create a thread is:

```
my $thr = server::start_thread(\&_start_server_process,$sServerType,$sIcPipe,$rIcSock,'thread');


sub start_thread {

    my $thr = threads->create(@_) or return;

    return $thr;

}
```

**Edit 2**
Log output from successful and unsuccessful calls are as below:

```
Successful accept:
2014-09-22 08:55:32,575 p:2532.5    e:2532.5   s:OA.2  DEBUG : CADETserver::channel_accept - !!! - TCP socket accept. Channel=oa rH=IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x743c4ac)
2014-09-22 08:55:32,635 p:2532.5    e:2532.5   s:OA.2  DEBUG : CADETserver::channel_accept - !!! - TCP socket accept result. Channel=oa $@= $rClient=IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x9fb2d3c)

Unsuccessful accept:
2014-09-22 08:55:32,575 p:2532.6    e:2532.6   s:OA.3  DEBUG : CADETserver::channel_accept - !!! - TCP socket accept. Channel=oa rH=IO::Socket::INET=GLOB(0x7aef7d4)
2014-09-22 08:55:32,606 p:2532.6    e:2532.6   s:OA.3  DEBUG : CADETserver::channel_accept - !!! - TCP socket accept result. Channel=oa $@= $rClient=
```

Note that we're just getting an *undef* client socket and no error recorded in *$@*

The code which produced the above log output is below - as you can see, we're just calling *accept* with no parameters.

```
my $rH = $rHndlHandles{$sCurrServerType}{$rSock};
$l4p->debug("!!! - TCP socket accept. Channel=$sChannel rH=$rH");
my $rClient;
eval {
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = 'IGNORE';
    $rClient =  $rH->accept();
};
$l4p->debug('!!! - TCP socket accept result. Channel=' . $sChannel . ' $@=' .$@ . ' $rClient=' . $rClient );
```

***Interestingly*** I was looking at whether the problem is how we're setting the socket to non-blocking. Our current code is as follows:

```
ioctl ($rSock, 0x8004667E, \$temp); # set non-blocking
```

When I change it to:

```
    use constant FIONREAD => 0x4004667f;
    my $numbytes = "\x00" x 4; # pack('L',0) works too
    ioctl($rSock, FIONREAD, unpack('I',pack('P',$numbytes)));
    my $nbytes = unpack('I',$numbytes);
```

(with thanks to bitshiftleft on PerlMonks - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=780083)

this allows the sockets to accept OK, but the sockets don't communicate reliably.

So... is it to do with how we're setting the sockets to non-blocking?

Comment: Is using threading an option, in lieu of using forks? Perl threads work quite a bit better on Windows I believe.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates threads, or at least show the output of debug print line you added for the case when accept succeeds, and for the case when it fails?

Comment: @sobrique - We are using threading, not forking.

Comment: @atcynth - I've added the threading call. Will add output from successful accept in due course. Thanks.

Comment: Are you starting one thread for each server socket, or creating one server socket and passing it to several threads?

Comment: The related SSL module has some advice http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-2.016/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod#Using_Non-Blocking_Sockets